# In danger of being blocked from asking questions for no apparent reason

Tags: discussion

I cannot see how I have done something wrong. My standing is good, one of my questions has 15 upvotes, none has negative standing. I have deleted one single question after I was notified it was inappropriate for this forum.

I respect the forums guidelines and feel that they are there to protect the quality of the forum, but I really don't see a reason for being this harsh to the new users.

Update:
After posting this question, moderators have reviewed my profile and given a very apparent reason for this warning. So, I end up with lots of downvotes here as well.

Comment: No answers.  Total of 5 questions.  3 of them closed.  1 of the remaining two has down- and close-votes.  That's not a particularly good standing.  Step-up your game.

Comment: Actually, my standing was decent before I started this thread. Now, moderators have been closing my posts and my standing has dropped. I find this kind of behavior quite repulsive. If my posts were really that bad, it should have been moderated a long time ago. Now, after starting this metapost, I am even closer to been blocked.

Comment: The posts that are closed [to date] have been closed weeks ago.  You have started this thread on meta 12 hours ago.  So, it was actually moderated some time ago as it should have been.  Please be more accurate with dates.

Answer (score 5):

Your question history has not been good.  This is warning you that if you continue like this, the system will take steps to protect itself from you asking more bad questions.  This is perfectly reasonable.  Whether this is harsh or not is immaterial.  The point is that it is effective.

You are not being singled out.  This is what happens to all those you can't grasp the rules, or don't care to learn them.  The way out of this is to carefully read the rules, look at exactly what was wrong with your previous questions, and then learn from that and stop asking bad questions.  If you can't or won't do that, we really don't want you around here.

You have asked three questions:

[Breadboard computer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/186974/4512)

This was well upvoted, and the leading answer was also highly upvoted.  The system probably considers this a good question.  However, it wasn't, and getting a good response to a bad question did you a disservice so that now you're in the situation you're in.  I hope some of the do-gooders that reply to stuff like this instead of voting to close see this example of how it not only hurts the site, but in this case hurt the asker.

The problem with this question is that it was way too broad.  Also asking *is it feasible* is just inviting opinions.  The reason this got erroneously upvoted and allowed to live was because it was a popular topic.  This always brings out the unwashed masses who just can't resist chiming in, and who can't distinguish between *I like this topic* and *this topic belongs here*.

[Textbook for learning analog IC design?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/186884/4512)

This is the poster case for asking for shopping advice and for soliciting opinions.  We have specific close reasons for both.  Clearly you hadn't bothered to learn the rules, or thought you were above them if you did. If you still don't see how this doesn't belong here, then you don't belong here either.

[Designing logic for 7-segment display](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/192213/4512)

I ran into that question before seeing your question here on meta, and you can see the comment I left.  This question is too broad, and I voted to close it on those ground.  I did not downvote it, but I can see the point of view behind that.

You are asking for a whole design.  You said yourself *"I am not really sure where to start"*.  That should have been a warning.  We're not here for that.  You have to bring something to the table.  Surely there is something you already know about this.  Start there, then ask a specific question about what specifically you are stuck on.

If you don't even know where to start, one wonders why you picked this as a project.  If the point is to learn to design some combinatorial logic to a spec, then it makes sense to start with something you have at least a little idea how it works and try to expand your knowledge.  If the point is to have a BCD to 7-segment decoder, then why not simply buy one?  These questions in my mind when I encountered your question contributed to convincing me it doesn't belong here.

Comment: How can a quite highly rated question be bad? If it is bad according to the rules, then the rules clearly doesn't reflect the general opinion of the users of this site. If the voting system promotes "bad questions" like this, it is clearly broken and maybe even redundant.

Comment: @C.T.: I already answered this.

Comment: @C.T.  Related to Olin's item 1 : [Question closed because yes/no answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/254079) "When asking a yes/no question there are one of two possibilities...", and [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/).

Answer (score 2):

The system may be picking up on the closed question and the one with negative rep.

I honestly don't know how the exact maths are behind the screens, but if you'd mask out the amount of upvotes and only look at whether a question was very well received or not, your effective score would now be "below zero" on the ones not yet deleted.

Looking with a human eye at your questions does tell me that you are not in danger of being actively shunned yet, the closed question is still valuable in my personal opinion.

None the less, the warning the system gives you to think carefully about your next question is valid. Below 1k rep you're in danger of people forming opinions about you that influence their answering next time based on just one or two questions.

I don't believe this is the system trying to be harsh on you, but it is warning you that a small mistake may cost you answers to an otherwise valid question. It is an unfortunate side effect of how people think about each other, certainly no less so in an engineering field. Let alone when "we" volunteer our time to what we decide to answer, making us undoubtedly even more harsh on balance in that decision.

Take it as the warning it is and be a little extra careful the next few questions you ask.